# Body of If statement runs no matter what input

Tags: c, if-statement

I have a feeling this is going to be some really simple mistake, but whatever character I type into the program, the 'help screen' is still displayed. I've been looking at how to fix for a while and cannot crack it, as I said, I have a feeling it will be something really stupid and simple. I haven't had much experience with C, so apoligies for any amateur mistakes. 
Which symbols are for assignment and which for comparison in C? (*= and ==*)

```
int initialSelection(){
printf( "                                Welcome to Anagramania!\n");
printf( "Please press (s) to start or (h) to view the help screen\n");
initialChoice = getchar();
    if (initialChoice = 'h'){ //Display help screen
        system("cls");
        printf( "                                Anagramania Help Screen\n");
        printf( "Welcome to Anagramia, created by Toby Cannon. There are three levels of difficulty in this game, easy, medium, or hard! How good do you think you are? Once you start the game you will see some jumbled letters on the screen. You're job is to guess what word these letters have come from! There is 20 words in each game, and you can review your game at the end. \n Good luck!\n");
            getch(); //wait for user input
            system("cls"); //Clear the console
        }
}
```

Comment: For comparaison use  '=='  not '='

Answer (score 2, accepted):

needs to look like this: `if (initialChoice == 'h')` so you are actually checking whether the expression on the left equals that on the right

Answer (score 7):

`=` is *assignment*, so what your code was doing was *assigning* `'h'` to `initialChoice` and then testing the result, which is the value `'h'` (the value of an assignment expression is the value that was assigned). That ends up testing true, so the body of the `if` is executed.

`==` is equality comparison. So:

```
if (initialChoice == 'h'){
// Note -----------^
```

Any decent compiler should have "lint" features that warn you when you do this. (Search for "warnings" in the documentation.)

Comment: `if(initialChoice = 'h')` returns true because of assignment was successfull and it returns true, its like the reusult of assignment

Comment: @tema , Actually, it returns true as `h` is a non-zero number. (The check happens after the assignment)

Comment: @TobyCannon , Use [Yoda Conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions) to prevent these kind of small issues

Comment: @CoolGuy: Better yet, use the lint tools of the compiler to avoid backward saying things.

Comment: @tema: "returns true because of assignment was successfull" that doesn't matter! there is no case an simple asignment to a lvalue would fail on runtime without leading to programm termination. So there is also no reason to differ between succesfull an unsuccesfull assignment. the only reason this evaluates as true is, because by semantic rules the condition in the end is (as already stated) `'h'` what is `!= 0`.